# LWC lightning file upload validation

Tags: lightning-web-components

Does the LWC component  support pre-validation before file get uploaded? I checked the js library doesnt seems have any way to do the validation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does no pre-validation at all. It is essentially just a mechanism to upload files to a record. If you want comprehensive validation, write your own component instead.

Comment: Apex has limit of 6mb. I need to upload a file up to 20mb. Is there a way can do that?